# How to fix `Expression 'jar' cannot be invoked as a function` error in gradle file?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following gradle file. I'm getting a `Expression 'jar' cannot be invoked as a function` error on the line where `jar` is used (`jar {`). How can I fix this?

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    java
    application
}

group = "me.talha"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MainKt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not need to add any of the jar stuff. I can simply use the gradle `distZip` task which generates the needed jars and executable scripts and all works fine.